# cant adjust player movement to within boundary

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi i'm trying to set a boundary where if my player walks backward past a certain point, its position is readjusted to within the boundary. Here is my code in GameManager.cs:

```
Vector3 pos = player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position;

Update() {
    if (pos.z <= -20)
    {
        print("XCzxczczxczxcxzc");
        float newX = pos.x;
        float newY = pos.y;
        pos = new Vector3(newX, newY, 0);
    }

}
```

From this code, obviously i have a rigidbody attached to my player which is a capsule primitive. However for some reason it just keeps moving past the specified boundary. Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `pos` variable isn't the actual position of the Rigidbody, it's merely a copy of its value at the time it was assigned.

Rather than making a variable for the position, make a variable for the Rigidbody, and use that reference (along with `.position`) when making changes.

```cs
Rigidbody body = player.GetComponent<RigidBody>();

void Update() {
    Vector3 pos = body.position; 

    if (pos.z <= -20) {
        float newX = pos.x;
        float newY = pos.y;
        body.position = new Vector3(newX, newY, 0); 
    }
}
```